# Python list for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a function that I saw to find the unique items in an array in order, I am new to python but this seemed very elegant.

```
unique_in_order = lambda l: [z for i, z in enumerate(l) if i == 0 or l[i - 1] != z]
```

How does this for loop *exactly* work.

```
z for i,z in enumerate(l)
```

Comment: TBH, that is not an elegant way to find unique items.

Comment: FYI, `foo = lambda x: ...` is not considered a good idea in Python. Use `def foo(x): return ...` instead

Comment: and it doesn't look as if it is returning the unique items. It returns `z` if the element before it is not `z`. `l` has to be ordered for that to work.

Comment: elegance also means simple. This isn't simple. If you are new to python you should stay away from this sort of syntax.

Answer (score 1):

[`enumerate(..)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a builtin function that takes as input an iterable object (`l` here) and generates a sequence of tuples containing the *index* and the element for each element.

So `enumerate([1,4,2,5])` emits tuples like `(0,1)`, `(1,4)`, `(2,2)`, `(3,5)`. If you use a comma-separated list of identifiers in the head of the `for` loop, the tuple is untupled. So:

```
for i,z in enumerate([1,4,2,5]):
    pass
```

will iterate four times, the first time `i` will be `0` and `z` 1; the next iteration `i` will be `1` and `z` 4; the next iteration `i` will be `2` and `z` 2; the next iteration `i` will be `3` and `z` 5.

Now your statement also contains some *list comprehension*, the first `z` in `z for i,z in enumerate(l)` means it will emit the `z` values. Notice furthermore that there is condition (the `if` part), so not all values will be emitted.

Answer (score 0):

[enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html) helps you to iterate over both the indices and the items of sequences at once.

Here is an example :

```
>>> l=['a','b','c']
>>> for index,value in enumerate(l):
    print (index,value)

0 a
1 b
2 c
```

The solution you've posted is wrong and doesn't return unique elements as it only checks for duplicates on the previous item only (`l[i-1]!=z`).

To elaborate on what I meant, here is a test run :

```
>>> unique_in_order = lambda l: [z for i, z in enumerate(l) if i == 0 or l[i - 1] != z]
>>> l=[1,1,123,5,6,123]
>>> unique_in_order(l)
[1, 123, 5, 6, 123]
```

You can see that `123` occurs twice because it was tested only against its previous element `6`.

Before I provide a simple solution, we need to be clear that we are finding unique items from a list in order or we are trying to get rid of duplicates entirely.

A simple and elegant solution would be to use [`list.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method. It returns the number of times an item occurs in the list.

```
>>> l=['a', 'a',2,5,6,'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','e',2,2,6]
>>> [x for x in l if l.count(x)<2]
[5, 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

If you did not meant to discard the duplicates entirely and instead wanted the list to have a single occurence of the duplicate items then you can do this :

```
>>> l=['a', 'a',2,5,6,'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','e',2,2,6]
>>> dups=set()
>>> [x for x in l if x not in dups and (dups.add(x) or True)]
['a', 2, 5, 6, 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start with concept of [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) in python to understand what does this lambda function do. In short it creates list of `z` elements that meet a condition on right side of statement. 
Another important thing is builtin [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function that simply emits list of touples consisting of element and it's index.